# matching access_tokens to user_ids in an app server

Tags: oauth-2.0

Let's say, i want to develop a rest api implementation and use OAuth 2.0 with authorization_code grant. I will have apps, users, access_tokens etc. I just couldn't imagine only one scenario. When a user permits an app to use it, my auth server will redirects him to app site with auth code and then the app will post it with its client_id to fetch access_token. So, how can i link this access_code to the user? At last, the app will want to access to some resource about THE USER and will post the access_code which my auth server created to access it. Or just the app should store to link between access_code and the user id(but how can it determine the user, it is an another question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authorization server have to provide a service to give the resource server user information but using access_token so the resource server can get user Id and other information to use it, example of it is using login with FB or google, it is providing user information to the 3rd party want to authenticate this user.